# Посчитать количество вхождений символа в строке

Tags: javascript

Нужно создать функцию, которая принимает на вход строку и символ и считает количество повторений символа в строке. Функция должна возвращать число. Я не понимаю, какие условные операторы нужно поставить в цикл, чтобы функция заработала.

```
    let counter = 0;

    while (counter <= str.length) {

        if (   ) {
            counter = counter + 1;
            return counter;
        }
        else {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: как вариант, разбить строку на массив символов, к полученному массиву применить `filter`, получить длину полученного массива. пример: `[...'abca'].filter(letter => letter === 'a').length`

Comment: Посчитать уменьшение длины строки - исходная минус после замены указанного символа на пустую строку. Типа `str.length - str.replace(symbol, '').length` (синтаксис причесать самостоятельно).

Comment: @Akina в этом же случае надо цикл, или же использовать регулярку для удаления всех вхождений, правильно?

Comment: Вообще-то народ говорит, что у объекта String имеется метод Replace... [JavaScript String replace() Method](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp). Нет, если очень хочется, то можно и цикл... Или, если заменять совсем не нравится, то можно и просто `str.split(symbol).length` (метод split у string тоже имеется).

Comment: @Akina вы не поняли, [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace), без указания регулярки заменит только **первое вхождение**, если искомый символ задан в виде строки, а если в виде регулярки то можно вырезать все вхождения

Comment: Ну укажите модификатор `/g`, сложно, что ли?

Answer (score 1):

Вот так можно.

```js
let counter = 0;

let str = 'This is a string';
let char = 's';

function count(str, ch) {
  for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    if (str[i] === ch) counter++;
  }
}

count(str, char);
console.log(counter);
```